# Is there any way to make sure that an image is not taken from Google but instead the user's phone camera?

Tags: image, camera, artificial-intelligence, google-image-search

I want to only allow images that are taken directly with the phone’s camera on my web site. Are there any APIs or tricks that could help me tell if an image is authentic and taken with an iPhone or Android camera a few moments ago and not taken from Google Images.

Comment: Hard to make it tamper-proof, but you could ask them to do something they couldn't anticipate which would be simple if they are a straight but hard if they are trying to get around your restriction. E.g. say the first picture was blurry, please re-shoot and then check the two images are slightly different but the GPS location and time are very similar. Or ask them to place a coin, or foot or hand in left-top, bottom-right corner or some such. Or ask for a 3-second video as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [drstuggels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5180819/drstuggels) they are a few ways to go about this.

## WebRTC

To prevent upload from any file, take picture directly on your web interface, via the user webcam.
You would need to

1. Ask permission to the user to use the webcam.
2. Open the video stream
3. Capture on click the frame
4. Save the frame

This would prevent lambda users from uploading picture "not live".
If this is a solution you are considering, look for [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/). Although there are many blog post showcasing demo for this exact use case.

Such as:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

## EXIF validation

As mentioned by [iѕєρєня](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893439/i%D1%95%D1%94%CF%81%D1%94%D0%BD%D1%8F), you could try to access the [EXIF metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) of the uploaded picture and run a validation mechanism, for let say freshness but looking for date and time field (if you are looking for a newly taken photo) or the camera model field to make sure it was taken by a camera (phone, DSLR, etc..).

**DISCLAIMER:**
Nothing will prevent a malicious user from tampering with the js code or file to upload fake picture.

Comment: what if someone wanted to open the website on their computer that has no camera? I think the best way to differ a downloaded image from a directly taken from phone camera is the `EXIF/Metadata` of the image. most of the times downloaded/uploaded images lose their metadata, but a phone taken photo always have some metadata that grouped under `Camera` header. it can be extracted with some libraries like [Exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) before even they upload their photo.

Comment: I agree, this is also a valid approach !
It is still easy to circumvent, as tampering with exif is possible. But I guess there are not silver bullet (to my knowledge)

Comment: well there is no way to really understand that, but it's always good to know your program audiences, like their age, their average computer knowledge and how much this program tempt them to tamper the input data. but as for a normal computer/mobile user with average knowledge both ways should work.

Comment: I have edited my answer to take you input into account, but if you feel I should had anything, or word it differently let me know. (or if you can edit it please do)

Comment: I submitted a simple edit just to complete the answer. (:

Comment: Yeah this is pretty good. I'm luckily not interested in making my site work on desktop. And banning users that try to do some mitm shit is gonna be easy. But if anyone has some additional ideas that could make the validation process even more secure, I will gladly hear them, since the harder it is to tamper with the request, the better.